# How to make Kodi something you can run from Ubuntu login screen without password?

Tags: 18.04, sound, bluetooth, kodi

It would be nice to be able to watch TV without needing to enter password ;)

Additionally, I would like it to use bluetooth for audio. I read [somewhere](https://kodi.wiki/view/Kodi_v18_(Leia)_changelog#Other) that Kodi 18 has some improvements regarding bluetooth, and I could install that from a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~team-xbmc/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). If I run Kodi from a desktop environment I can connect bluetooth device using graphical tools i.e. `blueman-applet`  and `pavucontrol` (to control Pulseaudio), but I can not use them when I run Kodi from the login screen as standalone app if I may say so.

Comment: One thought: Create user account `tv` that doesn't require password and auto starts kodi.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix that might be a solution. IIRC guest sessions are no more supported in 18.04.

Comment: I also read random guest session support has been dropped. But it only takes a few minutes to setup a new ID which would function like a persistent guest anyway. If you have kids you can install `lock-screen-timer` to limit TV screen time to 1 hour, 2 hours, etc: https://askubuntu.com/questions/837078/application-that-will-lock-screen-after-a-set-amount-of-time-for-ubuntu/837115#837115

Comment: Have you tried installing **LibreELEC** to it's own partition, then you should be able to run Kodi from the computers grub menu.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron No I haven't. Version 9 of it might still do, but in upcoming version 10 there is no support for NVIDIA GPU.  [see here](https://libreelec.wiki/)